# How to inject service on component

Tags: angularjs, sweetalert, angular-components

I am having issues to use SweetAlert from component, 
I tried to load it from parent and its all works bug not on component.
The error :

> Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: SweetAlertProvider <- SweetAlert

My code is:

```
(function () {
'use strict';

angular.module("app.my.component", [])
    .component("myCard", {
        templateUrl: "app/views/my.card.template.html",


        bindings: {


        },

        controller: ComponentController
    });
ComponentController.$inject = ['fetchComponentService','SweetAlert'];
function ComponentController(fetchComponentService,SweetAlert) {
    var vm = this;
```

Comment: Are you sure you have the SweetAlert provider/service declared to the same module as your newly created component?  You shouldn't be creating a new angular module just for your component and that's what it 'appears' you are doing.

Comment: other controller that aren't component is using it with this name with injection.

Comment: I'm not sure if you're understanding me or maybe I am not understanding you.  Just to be fully explicit, if the rest of your application is decalred to Angular like so: `angular.module("app", [])` then you need to do the same thing for this component.  Otherwise your provider/service is only known to the "app" module and not the "app.my.component" module.  Again, I am not sure if you've actually made this mistake but I'm just putting it out there as that is what it looks like.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Find the issue, I didn't require it on navigate from parent that calling it :

```
 require: ['oitozero.ngSweetAlert'],
```